# Error installing tsflex on Mac: "Failed building wheel for fastparquet"

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastparquet

I've come across an issue while attempting to install the tsflex package on my Mac using pip3. After running pip3 install tsflex, I received the following error message:

```
Collecting tsflex
  Using cached tsflex-0.1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
Collecting dill<0.4.0,>=0.3.3 (from tsflex)
  Using cached dill-0.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (110 kB)
Collecting fastparquet<0.7.0,>=0.6.3 (from tsflex)
  Using cached fastparquet-0.6.3.tar.gz (318 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0,>=1.19.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tsflex) (1.24.3)
Collecting pandas<2.0.0,>=1.2.3 (from tsflex)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (10.8 MB)
Collecting pathos<0.3.0,>=0.2.7 (from tsflex)
  Using cached pathos-0.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.60.0 (from tsflex)
  Using cached tqdm-4.65.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting thrift>=0.11.0 (from fastparquet<0.7.0,>=0.6.3->tsflex)
  Using cached thrift-0.16.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_13_0_arm64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cramjam>=2.3.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from fastparquet<0.7.0,>=0.6.3->tsflex) (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from fastparquet<0.7.0,>=0.6.3->tsflex) (2023.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas<2.0.0,>=1.2.3->tsflex) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas<2.0.0,>=1.2.3->tsflex) (2023.3)
Collecting ppft>=1.7.6.5 (from pathos<0.3.0,>=0.2.7->tsflex)
  Using cached ppft-1.7.6.6-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting pox>=0.3.1 (from pathos<0.3.0,>=0.2.7->tsflex)
  Using cached pox-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting multiprocess>=0.70.13 (from pathos<0.3.0,>=0.2.7->tsflex)
  Using cached multiprocess-0.70.14-py310-none-any.whl (134 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas<2.0.0,>=1.2.3->tsflex) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: fastparquet
  Building wheel for fastparquet (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [143 lines of output]
      /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/encoding.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/dataframe.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/compression.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/thrift_structures.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/core.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/converted_types.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/api.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/schema.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      running egg_info
      writing fastparquet.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to fastparquet.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to fastparquet.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to fastparquet.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'fastparquet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'fastparquet/test/'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'fastparquet/benchmarks/'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'test-data/'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'fastparquet.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:201: _Warning: Package 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
      
              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.
      
              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
      
              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html
      
              If you don't want 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.
      
              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html
      
      
              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:201: _Warning: Package 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
      
              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.
      
              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
      
              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html
      
              If you don't want 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.
      
              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:
      
              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html
      
      
              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying fastparquet/cencoding.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/cencoding.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/parquet.thrift -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/speedups.c -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      copying fastparquet/speedups.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift
      copying fastparquet/parquet_thrift/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet
      copying fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet
      copying fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet
      copying fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet/ttypes.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/parquet_thrift/parquet
      running build_ext
      building 'fastparquet.speedups' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk -I/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -I/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c fastparquet/speedups.c -o build/temp.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-311/fastparquet/speedups.o
      fastparquet/speedups.c:209:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
        #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastparquet
  Running setup.py clean for fastparquet
Failed to build fastparquet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastparquet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm using python3.9. I have Xcode Command Line Tools installed, and I also made sure that the snappy library is installed using Homebrew.
I have tried upgrading pip, setuptools, Cmake, and wheel to their latest versions. However, I'm still unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your error is strange... Fastparquet ships binary wheels for [a number](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/#files) of OS and architecture mixes that ought to include yours, and so not need any local building.

Having said that, I suspect the problem is probably originating in a mix of libraries between python and whatever homebrew is doing. You *could* try removing the bundled C source - but this is tricky when things are hidden behind an opaque layer by the pip process.

Actually the best way to install binary things, python-specific or otherwise, is to use the conda ecosystem. This makes far more extensive account for architecture and consistency of all the related packages; for instance, it will provide its own variety of snappy rather than need you to install it via other means.